# Why don't we call gravitational field as acceleration since both of these quantities are Force/mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, field-theory, terminology

We know that *gravitational field is given by the formula $F/m$*; where $F$ is gravitational force and $m$ is the unit mass that we are using to calculate the field.

But we also know that *$F/m$ is acceleration*.

***So how is field different from acceleration?***

Comment: It is indeed called the free fall acceleration

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)#Field_theory

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a slight misunderstanding what a physical equation means. Such an equation relating two or more quantities does not mean that the quantities on both sides are the same *entity/object/thing*. An equation like $\vec{F}_{\mathrm{grav}}=m\vec{a}$ does not mean, that the gravitational force applied to a body, on the left, is the same *quantity* as the acceleration times the mass of that body (which would also not make sense, because the gravitational field is independent of any other external body, for example the gravitational field of the earth is independent of you), but it means that the grav. force on the body *causes* the body to accelerate, and that this acceleration has absolute value $|\vec{F}/m|$ and has the same direction as the force.

That all of these are different quantities in general, you can realise by remembering that the full equation of Newton's axiom is actually $\sum_i \vec{F_i}=m\vec{a}$, where you have to add all the forces that are acting on the body. If, additionally to the force caused by gravity, there is also acting a force, e.g. because of friction, or an electric field (if the body is charged), then $\vec{F}_{\mathrm{grav}}$ is not just $m\vec{a}$. You are probably on earth right now, and maybe sit or stand somewhere. This means there is gravitational force acting on you, but you still do not accelerate.

(I am aware that the connection between acceleration and gravity is viewed deeply differently in general relativity, and that the answer to 'how is the field different from acceleration' is way more involved there, but I do not think that this is the question here.)